# How to use arm-linux-gcc cross compile gmock?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I get one **C++ source code** and the project structure as follow:

```
|-+ ACode
    |-+ src //include code
    |-+ include //include .h file
    |-+ test
    |-+ CMakeLists.txt
 .... //similar to the ACode 
|-+ build
|-+ doc
|-+ ThirdParty
    |-+ googletest-release-1.8.0
        |-+ googlemock
        |-+ googletest
        |-+ CMakeLists.txt
    |-+ MultipartParser
    |-+ rapidjson
    |-+ CMakeLists.txt
    |-+ googletest.cmake
|-+ tests
|-+ CMakeLists.txt
```

I used cmake -> make can build success and can execute success on linux platform.

Now i want to use `arm-linux-gcc` cross compile it.

Get the **error message** after modifying the project **CMakeLists.txt** file.
CMakeLists.txt file add follow content:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/../../toolschain/4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-gcc")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/../../toolschain/4.4.3/bin/arm-linux-g++")
```

Get **error** message while used make command:

> Scanning dependencies of target gmock_main
>   [  1%] Building CXX object ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/CMakeFiles/gmock_main.dir/__/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc.o
>   [  2%] Building CXX object ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/CMakeFiles/gmock_main.dir/src/gmock-all.cc.o
>   In file included from /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:58,
>                    from /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/src/gmock-all.cc:40:
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h: In static member function 'static Result testing::internal::ReturnNullAction::Perform(const ArgumentTuple&)':
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h:631: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
>   In file included from /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:75,
>                    from /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:43,
>                    from /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:61,
>                    from /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/src/gmock-all.cc:40:
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: In member function 'bool testing::internal::IsNullMatcher::MatchAndExplain(const Pointer&, testing::MatchResultListener*) const':
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:983: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: In member function 'bool testing::internal::NotNullMatcher::MatchAndExplain(const Pointer&, testing::MatchResultListener*) const':
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1003: error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: At global scope:
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1560: sorry, unimplemented: cannot expand 'Tail ...' into a fixed-length argument list
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1561: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1561: error: 'ListType' in class 'int' does not name a type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1561: error: template argument 2 is invalid
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1561: error: expected '::' before 'ListType'
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: In static member function 'static int testing::internal::MatcherList::BuildList(const Head&, const Tail& ...)':
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1568: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1568: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1568: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1568: error: 'BuildList' is not a member of 'int'
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: In static member function 'static testing::Matcher testing::internal::MatcherList::CreateMatcher(const int&)':
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1578: error: request for member 'first' in 'matchers', which is of non-class type 'const int'
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: 'CreateMatcher' is not a member of 'int'
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1580: error: request for member 'second' in 'matchers', which is of non-class type 'const int'
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1577: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1578: error: request for member 'first' in 'matchers', which is of non-class type 'const int'
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: 'CreateMatcher' is not a member of 'int'
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1579: error: missing template arguments before '>' token
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1580: error: request for member 'second' in 'matchers', which is of non-class type 'const int'
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: At global scope:
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1623: sorry, unimplemented: cannot expand 'Args ...' into a fixed-length argument list
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1625: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1625: error: 'ListType' in class 'int' does not name a type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: In constructor 'testing::internal::VariadicMatcher::VariadicMatcher(const Args& ...)':
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1611: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1611: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1611: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1611: error: 'BuildList' is not a member of 'int'
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: In member function 'testing::internal::VariadicMatcher::operator testing::Matcher() const':
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1618: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1618: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1618: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1618: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1618: error: 'int' is not a class type
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1618: error: 'CreateMatcher' is not a member of 'int'
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1618: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1618: error: missing template arguments before '>' token
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h: At global scope:
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1631: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:1725: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
>   In file included from /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:75,
>                    from /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:43,
>                    from /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock.h:61,
>                    from /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/src/gmock-all.cc:40:
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:4363: error: expected initializer before '<' token
>   /../../Linux+C/Temp/20170414/alexa-client-sdk-master/ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h:4368: error: expected initializer before '<' token
>   make[2]: *** [ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/CMakeFiles/gmock_main.dir/src/gmock-all.cc.o] Error 1
>   make[1]: *** [ThirdParty/googletest-release-1.8.0/googlemock/CMakeFiles/gmock_main.dir/all] Error 2
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

Can anyone help me how to modify the CMakeLists.txt file?
Or did i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

My solutions:

you just add CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE to the main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.2)                                                                                                                                                                       


project( googletest-distribution )                                              


enable_testing()                                                                


# add CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE to here to support cross compilling.
if(NOT CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
    # nothing to do
else()
    # nothing to do
endif()                                                                         


option(BUILD_GTEST "Builds the googletest subproject" ON)                       


#Note that googlemock target already builds googletest                          

option(BUILD_GMOCK "Builds the googlemock subproject" OFF)                      


if(BUILD_GMOCK)                                                                 
    add_subdirectory( googlemock )                                                

elseif(BUILD_GTEST)                                                             
    add_subdirectory( googletest )                                                

endif()
```

Cross compilling step:

```
mkdir build_linux_armv7
cd build_linux_armv7
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain.cmake
make
make install
```

toolchain.cmake context:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)                                                                                                                                                                                

set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING TRUE)                                                  

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER                                                          
    /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)                                           

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER                                                            
    /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)                                           

#set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH                                                       

#    /your_compiler_root_directory/)                                            

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)                                    

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)                                     

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
```